# Specifying multiple (active model) serializers in a larger, grouped JSON response in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I have a bigger sized JSON response in a controller method:

```
render json: {
    user: { id: @current_user.id, 
                    name: @current_user.full_name,
                    title: @current_user.title,
                    phone_work: @current_user.phone_work,
                    phone_mobile: @current_user.phone_mobile,
                    addresses: @current_user.addresses },
    appointments: @current_user.appointments
}
```

I tried doing `AppointmentSerializer.new(@current_user.appointments)` and I got this error: `undefined method 'read_attribute_for_serialization'`.  The error is coming from the first line, where the json is rendered (`render json:`).

How can I specify different serializers for the user, for the user's addresses, and for the appointments?

Answer (score 0):

there is a key-points to reply your question, what version of AMS are you using?

As a contributor to AMS I'd strongly advise you to keep and eye at our [GitHub](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), we are actively working on the new version 0.10.0 (that might become 1.0), it is supposed to be release next month. So keep in mind that you can update it soon and avoid some old issues.

About your question, it seems to me that you could have forgotten to include `serialization` module to your model. Just add it and you might be fine.

`include ActiveModel::Serialization`

You can see the reference to this at the old 0.9 version [README](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable)

Comment: Version 0.8 is what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I managed do this by merging both serializers, not the ideal, but:

```rb
response = AppointmentSerializer.new(@current_user.appointments).as_json

response.merge(UserSerializer.new(@current_user).as_json)

render json: response
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ActiveModel::Serializer`, you can create a custom serializer in his properly folder and call `render json: current_user, each_serializer:CustomUserSerializer`

on serializer:

```
class CustomUserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :title, :phone_work, :phone_mobile, :addresses 
  has_many :appointments 
end
```